# Wrap flex items in 2 columns for medium and smaller devices in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to get my hands on Tailwind and aiming to wrap items into 2 column layout for medium and smaller devices. It's very easy to do this by using Grid, but the Flex is wrapping all the items into a single column or will show 1 item in a single row for tab and mobile.

I would like to switch into 2 column layout for tab and mobiles irrespective of the number of items. Eg: If there are 3 items, then 2 should be in a single row and the third one in the second row. This is what I have tried till now:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center"> 
<div class="sm:basis:1/2 md:basis-1/2 lg:basis-1/4 xl:basis-1/5 mb-8 relative"> 
<p>Item1</p> 
<p>Item2</p> 
<p>Item3</p> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've tried up till now. And to understand this right you want to use `grid` right?

Comment: @M.G.updated. I want to use flex which is being used in the code

Answer (score -1):

The `flex-basis` was the right way to go but they need to applied to the individual blocks not the container as shown below. You can see the results on the Tailwind Playground link below too.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/vsPiSun9Jv

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-start">
  <div class="bg-blue-300 relative h-14 basis-1/2 lg:basis-1/4 xl:basis-1/5">Item1</div>
  <div class="bg-emerald-300 relative h-14 basis-1/2 lg:basis-1/4 xl:basis-1/5">Item2</div>
  <div class="bg-red-300 relative h-14 basis-1/2 lg:basis-1/4 xl:basis-1/5">Item3</div>
</div>
```